# Significato di "sbraghellato"

Tags: word-meaning, regional, adjectives

Nella commedia *Sotto paga! Non si paga!* di Dario Fo (testo aggiornato nel 2007 e pubblicato da Einaudi) ho letto:

> Accidenti, come gli assomiglia!... Assomiglia
>   sputato anche all’appuntato di Pubblica Sicurezza senza
>   baffi... Ah, ah, scusi se rido, non è per lei, ma mi sembra
>   di essere in una commedia che ho visto quando ero ragazzo... sa, una di quelle compagnie un po’ **sbraghellate**... dove, siccome avevano scarsità di interpreti, a uno stesso attore gli facevano fare tutte le parti dei poliziotti che c’erano nella commedia.

Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa "sbraghellato"? Non ho trovato questo vocabolo su nessun dizionario. Si tratta di un termine di origine dialettale?

Comment: Di origine dialettale da braghe o brache, ossia, pantaloni. Vedi sbracato: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sbracato/. Il senso è quello di essere senza pantaloni o con i pantaloni indossati malamente, per dare l’idea di qualcosa di poco efficiente o affidabile.